# How can I start Integrating Safe wallets for AA

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, safe

I had a couple of questions regarding AA in safe wallets.

1. Does Safe Wallet support AA by default?
2. While using the AA SDK, it says it generates an EOA, does it also create a smart contract wallet at the same time? If not then how can proceed with that EOA to create and use the Smart Wallet (ERC4337 compatible)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Safe Wallet "supports AA by default". Since it is a smart contract wallet it implements account abstraction by abstracting away a number of features, such as recovery mechanisms or sponsored transactions. You can read more on that [here](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/safe-smart-account).
2. You can create a Safe wallet after you logged in using [`safeAuth`](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/auth-kit/guides/safe-auth) and then triggering a [`deploySafe`](https://docs.safe.global/safe-core-aa-sdk/protocol-kit/reference#deploysafe) transaction. Note that logging in (and creating an EOA if you are using social login) and deploying a Safe are two different operations.

Hope it helps,
Louis